# HTML Agility Pack tr insertion at the end of a table

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have this table

```
<div id="ConversationDIv" runat="server">
   <table border="1" id="tbl">
       <tr>
          <td>blah blah</td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</div>
<asp:Button id="Insert" onCLick="Insert_Click" Text="addNew" ></asp:Button>
```

c# :

```
protected void Insert_Click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    html.LoadHtml(ConversationDIv.InnerHtml);

    var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table").FirstOrDefault();
    // how can I add a new row to table ?
}
```

I want to add a new row to the table how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution that i found it perfect :

```
protected void AddNewMessageRow(string rowToAppend)
{
    var html = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    html.LoadHtml(ConversationDIv.InnerHtml);
    var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table").FirstOrDefault();
    var node = HtmlNode.CreateNode(rowToAppend);
    table.AppendChild(node);
    ConversationDIv.InnerHtml += table.OuterHtml;
}

  string ToAppend = "<tr><td align='left' valign='top'  width='9%;'  ><img width='32px' height='32px' src='images/" + Session["ClientPicture"] + "'  /></td><td align='left' class='MiddleTd' valign='Top' ><span class='MsgSpan'>" + m + "</span></td><td align='right' align='left' valign='top' style='color:Gray;' >" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:tt") + "</td></tr>";
         AddNewMessageRow(ToAppend);
```

Comment: How it differs from my solution?

Answer (score 5):

You can use *SelectSingleNode* for selecting table. And use *HtmlNode.CreateNode* to create node being appended from html string:

```
var table = html.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table");
table.AppendChild(HtmlNode.CreateNode("<tr></tr>"));
```